# Bootstrap dropdown menu show on right side

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm creating a dropdown menu and I want to show the dropdown item on the right side. It's already working but somehow the dropdown not fully showed. The dropdown menu is inside sidebar, and when the space of sidebar is not enought. It will cut half of them.

My code is like this (sorry for inline css):

```
<div class="dropright">
    <button type="button" class="" style="background: none;
      color: inherit;
      border-top: 1px solid white;
      border-bottom: 1px solid white;
      border-left: 0;
      border-right: 0;
      padding: 10px 12px;
      font: inherit;
      cursor: pointer;
      align-items: center;
      width: 80%;
      outline: inherit;" 
      data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Items
    </button>
       
<div class="dropdown-menu" x-placement="right-start" 
      style="position: absolute; 
      transform: translate3d(111px, 0px, 0px); 
      top: 0px; 
      left: 0px; 
      will-change: transform;">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
 </div>

</div>
```

It become like picture bellow, half of them is behind.

[image: dropright]

[image: it was there]

And this is my sidebar code:

```
<div class="main-menu menu-fixed menu-dark menu-accordion menu-shadow" data-scroll-to-active="true">
<div class="main-menu-content">
        <ul class="navigation navigation-main" id="main-menu-navigation" data-menu="menu-navigation"
            data-icon-style="lines" style="position: relative">

            <li class=" navigation-header"><span>SUPER ADMIN</span>
            </li>

            <li class=" nav-item"><a href="{{ route('home') }}"><i class="menu-livicon"
                data-icon="line-chart"></i><span class="menu-title" data-i18n="home"><span
                    class="menu-title" data-i18n="home">Dashboard</span></a>
            </li>
     
            <div class="dropright">
                <button type="button" class="" style="background: none;
                color: inherit;
                border-top: 1px solid white;
                border-bottom: 1px solid white;
                border-left: 0;
                border-right: 0;
                padding: 10px 12px;
                font: inherit;
                cursor: pointer;
                align-items: center;
                width: 100%;
                outline: inherit;" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                 Items
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" x-placement="right-start" style="position: absolute; transform: translate3d(111px, 0px, 0px); top: 0px; left: 0px; will-change: transform;">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                </div>
              </div>

               
        
            <li class=" navigation-header"><span>MENU</span>
            </li>

    <li class=" nav-item"><a href="{{ route('home') }}"><i class="menu-livicon"
                data-icon="line-chart"></i><span class="menu-title" data-i18n="home"><span
                    class="menu-title" data-i18n="home">Data Master</span></a>
            </li>

         
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you fix it by adding `z-index: 10;` to the class `dropdown-item`?

or adding inline css as below:

```
    <a class="dropdown-item" style="z-index: 10;" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" style="z-index: 10;" href="#">Another action</a>
```

Source:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Comment: I have tried using z-index, but still not working

Comment: Kindly share proper code render view  as per stack overflow policy to test it properly and gives you proper answer, from shared image it will create unnecessary delay or answers

Comment: added sidebar code